# Can I use a heading element inside a label element?

Tags: html

Is it ok to put other elements like `<h1> <h2> <b>` inside `<label>` elements, or it is better to use style?

```
<label for="B"><b>like this</b></label>
<label for="h1"><h1>like this</h1></label>
```

it is working, but is it a good coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b), `font-weight` styles should be used over `<b>` (in general, not just in labels)

> However, you should not use `<b>` for styling text or granting importance. If you wish to create boldface text, you should use the CSS font-weight property. If you wish to indicate an element is of special importance, you should use the `<strong>` element.

As for headings, they are block level elements so should not be inside a label (which is an inline element). In general, headings should not be used to just change the font size of an element ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#usage_notes)).

Comment: So to make my web more readable for browsers it is better to use CSS for styling, but if I want to point out something specific it is better to use HTML tags that have meaning like `<strong>`

Comment: Correct. Use tags to convey meaning and structure. Use CSS to make it look good.

Answer (score -2):

Do not use headings for styling. That's not their purpose. Use them to create a sensible document structure in a logical cascade.